# What is the sql query to join command to join 2 tables from 2 different schemas

Tags: database, join, schema

What is the sql query to join command to join 2 tables from 2 different schemas,but which are present in single database.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you have to prefix tables with schema name (schema_A.table1 and schema_B.table1). Be sure to have read-access on these schemas when executing the query.